# no suitable method found for getDate(Date)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

I want to collect some data and store it to a database (in Java, using MySQL). One of the data is the Date (when this entry has been created/inserted).

I've already tried

```
private java.util.Date dateUtil = new java.util.Date();
private java.sql.Date dateSQL= new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime());
```

to convert the date to an sql-friendly format but I am still getting the error

> no suitable method found for getDate(Date)
>
> method ResultSet.getDate(int) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; Date cannot be converted to int)
>
> method ResultSet.getDate(String) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; Date cannot be converted to String)

The error occurs in line

```
System.out.println("(" + resSet.getInt(1) + ")"
...
+ resultSet.getDate(dateSQL)
...
);
```

When I try using

```
resultSet.getDate(java.sql.Date(dateSQL.getTime())
```

or

```
resultSet.getDate(java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime())
```

I get an error, too:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbo: class sql
>
> location: package java

And yes, I've imported java.sql.Date but Netbeans tells me that this import is unused...

I really am at my wits' end... Does anybody have an idea what else to do?

P.S.: I've got the same problem with float:

```
+ resultSet.getFloat(somefloat)
```

Error Message:

> no suitable method found for getFloat(float)
>
> method ResultSet.getFloat(float) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from float int)
>
> method ResultSet.getFloat(String) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; float cannot be converted to String)

EDIT: A minimalist code snippet:

```
public class sqlTest
{
    public static DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
    private static PreparedStatement prepStatement;
    private static ResultSet resSet;

    private Date date;
    private float someFloat;
    

    public static void insertExample(Date date, float someFloat)
    {
        connection = (DBConnection) connection.getInstance();
        
        if(connection == null)
        {
            try
            {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO sample(date, someFloat) VALUES(?, ?)";
                
                prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                
                prepStatement.setDate(1, date);
                prepStatement.setFloat(2, someFloat);

                prepStatement.executeUpdate();
                
                String lastSample = "SELECT date, someFloat FROM SAMPLE";
                
                if(resSet.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("(" + resSet.getInt(1) + ")" + resSet.getDate(java.sql.Date(date.getTime())) + " " + resSet.getFloat(someFloat)); //here the error(s) occur
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException sqle)
            {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "SQLException was thrown while inserting sample: ", sqle.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect `getDate(Date)` to do? The `getDate` method is meant to retrieve a particular entry in the result set *as* a date...

Comment: Have a look at the API docs for ResultSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html. You will find there is no method with signature getDate(java.sql.Date).

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL. I expected getDate() to get the actual date and insert it to the databse... But seems like I'm wrong...

Comment: Also, it might be useful to see the original SQL query you ran. It might allow someone to help you with the correct usage of the result set.

Comment: `getDate(int columnIndex)` and `getFloat(int columnIndex)` are used to retrieve the value of the designated column in the current row of the ResultSet object as a date and float

Comment: I'd suggest you look carefully at the API documentation and a basic JDBC tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to persist a `java.util.Date` into a database in Java, you will have to convert it to `java.sql.Date`.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse("2006-12-31");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
```

Once converted you can use `setDate()` of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO sample(date, someFloat) VALUES(?, ?)";

PreparedStatement prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
PreparedStatement prepStatement1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sample");
prepStatement.setDate(1, sqlDate);
prepStatement.setFloat(2, 1.0f);
```

Finally you can retrieve like this

```
ResultSet rset = prepStatement1.executeQuery();
while(rset.next())
{
  String date = rset.getDate("date").toString();
  Float f = rset.getFloat("someFloat");
  System.out.println(date +" "+f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are forgetting to execute your fetch query. Do something like

   ```
   PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(lastSample);
   resSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

WHEN you are getting a resultset you might need to consider this:

You are not specifying the column index in the getDate method:

```
java.sql.Date result = resSet.getDate(0);
Float otherFloat = resSet.getDate(1);
```

But I couldn't found the resultset querying in your code.